# Javascript breakpoints not hit in Chromium Embedded Framework

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, chromium-embedded

I am attempting to set a breakpoint in my Javascript while running inside a Chromium Embedded Framework app. However, when I run the code that should trigger the breakpoint, the breakpoint is ignored and code execution continues right through it.

Further, if I try to force a jump to debug mode using the Javascript `debugger` statement, the application freezes at that point until I close the Dev Tools window, at which point the app crashes.

The behavior is identical to that described in [this forum thread](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=210), but that thread is nearly 3 years old, and the issue was deemed to have been fixed.

I am running in Release mode, and I have tried including `m_bExternalDevTools = true;` in the `ClientHandler::ClientHandler()` method as described [here](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10987&p=18242&hilit=javascript+breakpoint#p18242) to open dev tools in a separate window, but this causes the dev tools to not open at all.

I have also tried manually opening a new Chrome window to the remote-debugging-port, and while this did pause on the `debugger` statement, attempting to step forward or continue from that point crashes the app, as does hitting a standard breakpoint.

Has anyone else run into this problem, and if so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: Are you using CEF1 or CEF3?